# Como retornar valor de check marcado via ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Eu tenho um formulário de cadastro de alunos. Ele está todo pronto, a única coisa que estou tendo dificuldades é em retornar o valor de um checkbox, que no cadastro se refere ao aluno estar ativo ou não.

No formulário ele está assim:

```
<label>Ativo</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="disponivel" value="ativo">
```

No ajax eu pego o valor dele

```
$.ajax({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'ajax/cadastraAluno.php',
       data: {
              // outros dados
              ativo: $("#ativo").is(':checked')
             },
```

No arquivo cadastraAluno.php eu uso os dados formulário enviado para fazer o registro do aluno na tabela.

cadastraAluno.php

```
$ativo = $_POST['ativo'];

if($ativo == true){
    $codativo = '1';
} else {
    $codativo = '0';
}
```

Eu consigo cadastrar normalmente todos os outros dados, menos esse checkbox.

No banco, a coluna que registra esse dado está como "tinyint(1)"

Para mim é indiferente como ele vai estar no banco, pode ser int, boolean, qualquer coisa, desde que eu possa diferenciar com os dados,  se o aluno está ativo ou não.

Comment: Se na BD tens `tinyint` então deves passar um numero e não uma string. Testa tirar esse if/else e colocar assim: `$codativo = $ativo ? 1 : 0;`. Funcionou?

Answer (score 0):

```
Tente assim

<label>Ativo</label>  
<input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="disponivel" value="1">    


$.ajax({  
   method: 'POST',  
   url: 'ajax/cadastraAluno.php',  
   data: {  
          // outros dados  
          ativo: $("#ativo").val();  
         }    

**cadastraAluno.php**  
$codativo = $_POST['ativo'];  

if($codativo!=1){  
$codativo = '0';  
}
```

Comment: é possível pegar o val() de um checkbox? para mim só era possível pegar o check do checkbox com  .attr(), .prop() ou .is()